# Django, How to pass data object from one template to another template

Tags: python, django, templates, django-views

I have one data object list in the view and passing it to the template to summarize the the list. 
Now, from that template I want to take the data object to the next page (template) to display the details of the data object.

In my view.py

```
schools = PublicSchools.objects.all()
return render_to_response('searchresult.html', {'schools': schools}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

In my template searchresult.html, I am listing the summary data of schools.

In turn I want to send the single school object to the next template (dateils.html) to display the details of particular school.

Can some one please help?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write another view to handle your requirement

Try this sample code

**URL**

```
# pass the selected school id form template to your view   
url(r'^school/(?P<school_id>\d+)/$', schoolDetails),
```

**views**

```
def schoolDetails(request, school_id):
    try:
        school = PublicSchools.objects.get(pk=school_id)
    except school.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
    return render(request, 'detail.html', {'school': school})
```

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Yes, I have tried it. It solved my purpose. I have passed primary key of the data in the href, and from the pk value and used the url and view you have suggested. It worked. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Is there a way without having to query the database again?